# Pegar variavel de outra página

Tags: php, libcurl

Tenho essa página loadChannels.php com o código:

```
    <?php
session_start();
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

/* Captura a página */
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = (int)$_GET['page'];
} else {
    $page = 1;
}

/* Acessa o parquivo `lista` + número da página + `.m3u8` */
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/list/lista{$page}.m3u");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if (substr($info["http_code"], 0, 2) != 20) {
    die();
}

preg_match_all('/(tvg-logo="(?<logo>.*?)".+group-title="(?<group>.*?)",(?<nome>.*)\((?<ano>\d+)\)\s-\s(?<audio>\w+)\s-\s(?<qualidade>\d+\w).*(?:\n(?P<link>http?:\/\/.+)))/', $response, $channels, PREG_SET_ORDER);

/**
 * Cria a lista LI e escreve na tela.
 * Como vamos acessar via AJAX, o conteúdo
 * será retornado via JavaScript
 */

foreach($channels as $channel):
?>

<li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="<?php echo $channel["link"] ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $channel["logo"]?>"/>
        <div id="nome_bar"><?php echo $channel["nome"] ?></div>
        <div id="ano_bar"><?php echo $channel["ano"] ?></div>
    </a>
</li>
<?php $_SESSION['nome'] = $channel["nome"];
endforeach; ?>
```

index:

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>CINEPLAY</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.css">
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/mdb.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/cp.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="../img/favicon/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="../img/favicon/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="../img/favicon/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="../img/favicon/apple-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="../img/favicon/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="../img/favicon/apple-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="../img/favicon/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="../img/favicon/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="../img/favicon/apple-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="../img/favicon/android-icon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="../img/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="../img/favicon/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../img/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="../img/favicon/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="../img/favicon/ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
        <div style="position: relative; background-image: url('../img/favicon/favicon-96x96.png'); background-size: 28px 28px; background-repeat: no-repeat;"/>
        <div class="titulo-blog">CINEPLAY</a>
    </nav>
</header>

<div class="py-4"></div>
<div class="filmes">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                   <ul id="channels-list"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="fixed-bottom">
Nenhum dos arquivos mostrados aqui estão hospedados no servidor. Os links são fornecidos por outros usuários.<br>CinePlay © 2018
</footer>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../js/mdb.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jarallax.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jarallax-video.js"></script>
<script>
/* Define a página inicial */
let scrollPage = 0;

/* Cria uma função para detectar se o usuário rolou a barra até o final */
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       loadChannels();
   }
});

/* Utilizamos o método `on` para detectar o evento de clique de novos elementos */
$("#channels-list").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#modal").find(".modal-title").text( $(this).attr("title") );
    $("#modal").find(".modal-body")
        .empty()
        .append( "<iframe allowFullScreen='allowFullScreen' allowscriptaccess='always' src=\""+$(this).attr("href")+"\"></iframe>" ); //Altere essa linha para chamar outro arquivo

    $("#modal").modal("show");

    /*
     * Utilizamos esse evento para executar uma função ao fechar o modal
     * Caso o modal seja fechado sem remover o `iframe`, o player continuará funcionando.
     */
    $('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $("#modal iframe").remove();
    })
});

/*
 * Utilizamos esse evento para executar uma função ao fechar o modal
 * Caso o modal seja fechado sem remover o `iframe`, o player continuará funcionando.
 */
$('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $("#modal iframe").remove();
})

/**
 * Função responsável por realizar a requisição para `loadChannels.php`
 */
function loadChannels(page) {

    /* Realizamos a requisição e retornamos o resultado na variável `data` */
    $.get("loadChannels.php?page="+scrollPage, function(data) {

        /* Incrementamos o valor retornado na DIV indicada e somamos o valor de `scrollPage` + 1 */
        $("#channels-list").append(data);
        scrollPage++;
    });
}

/* Carregamos a primeira lista */
loadChannels();


</script>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title "><?php echo $_SESSION['nome'] ?></h4>

      </div>

      <div class="modal-body"><img src="<?php echo $channel["logo"]?>"/></div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href='whatsapp://send?text=StackOverflow'>
        <button type="button" class="btn whatsapp">WHASTAPP</button>
      </a>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">FECHAR</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ValdeirPsr da um help?

Comment: Se possível posta o código do `index` e como você está fazendo via `SESSION`.

Comment: Estou tentando só mostrar o titulo no modal... adicionei o código lá.

Comment: Você não vai conseguir utilizar variável em arquivos diferentes. A depender do que você queira fazer, é possível que funcione de uma outra forma.

Comment: antes de separar em dois arquivos estava funcionando apenas com %channel_nome% mas agora não dá mais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitua o trecho abaixo no seu *PHP*

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="<?php echo $channel["link"] ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $channel["logo"]?>"/>
        <div id="nome_bar"><?php echo $channel["nome"] ?></div>
        <div id="ano_bar"><?php echo $channel["ano"] ?></div>
    </a>
</li>
```

por

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="<?php echo $channel["link"] ?>" title="<?php echo $channel["nome"] ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $channel["logo"]?>"/>
        <div id="nome_bar"><?php echo $channel["nome"] ?></div>
        <div id="ano_bar"><?php echo $channel["ano"] ?></div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Acontece que `$(this).attr("title")` está tentando capturar o atributo *title* do elemento *anchor*, como esse atributo não funciona, ele não consegue substituir no *modal*.